# Devise not signing out

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, devise

I have a link to logout.

```
<a href="http://mydomain.lvh.me:3000/users/sign_out" data-method="delete" rel="nofollow">
    Sign Out
</a>
```

Which correctly executes the sign out action:

```
Started DELETE "/users/sign_out" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-02-08 15:04:06 -0200
Processing by DeviseCustom::SessionsController#destroy as HTML
  Parameters: {"authenticity_token"=>"WYMm9e4VMNgdDFXbl59TKyylhX+rZlWbWMF8lVEeves="}
  User Load (0.2ms)  SELECT `users`.* FROM `users` WHERE `users`.`id` = 150 LIMIT 1
   (0.1ms)  BEGIN
   (0.2ms)  COMMIT
Redirected to http://mydomain.lvh.me:3000/
Completed 302 Found in 4ms (ActiveRecord: 0.5ms)
```

I am customizing SessionsController but I am not redefining the destroy action.

```
class DeviseCustom::SessionsController < Devise::SessionsController
  respond_to :html, :js
  layout :false
  def create
    <MYCUSTOMCONTENT>
  end
end
```

But after doing all this, current_user still holds the information of the logged user.
Any help?

Comment: why don't you add the destroy action in sessionsController?

Comment: I tried it, same problem

Answer (score 1):

Ensure that you've included the default javascript files in your layout. There should be a line like:

```
<%= javascript_include_tag :defaults %>
```

in your layout.

need a logout via GET then add this to your

### config/initializers/devise.rb:

```
config.sign_out_via = :get
```

Comment: I dont think that I need sign_out_via get. I have added the parameter the attribute data-method="delete" and the action is being executed correctly. Anyway, I tested changing to get and it didnt work.

Comment: This worked for me. The default setting of "delete" did not work for me. Changing "delete" to "get" worked. I am interested in knowing what the difference is. I would imagine that "delete" destroys the session id. Not sure what "get" does. Any ideas?